# Open accordion on load with active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have an accordion on my website and I would like for the accordion to be open at the right level depending on where the active class is. I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euzpp4hx/).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.servicesub').find('.servicesubitem').click(function () {

    if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        //Collapse
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).removeClass('active');

       // $("#footer-wrapper").animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 'fast');
    } else {
        //Expand
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //hide other panels
        $(".servicesubli").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

        //$("#footer-wrapper").animate({marginTop: "200px"}, 'fast');

    }

});




});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 servicesub" id="servicesub" >
<li class="servicesubitem active">
                            <span class="subitem">Web Design,
                                <br>
                                Multimedia &amp; Email</span><span class="fa1 fa-globe"> </span>
                        </li>
                        <div class="servicesubli">
                            <ul>
                                <a href="domains.php">
                                <li>
                                    Domain Registration
                                </li>
                                </a>
                                <a href="webdesign.php">
                                <li>
                                    Web Design &amp; Development
                                </li>
                                </a>
                                <a href="webhosting.php">
                                <li>
                                    Web Hosting
                                </li>
                                </a>
                                <a href="email.php">
                                <li>
                                    Managed Email Systems
                                </li>
                                </a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <li class="servicesubitem">
                            <span class="subitem">Vessel
                                <br>
                                Security</span><span class="fa1 fa-lock"> </span>
                        </li>
                        <div class="servicesubli">
                            <ul>
                                <a href="tracking.php">
                                <li>
                                    Yacht Tracking
                                </li>
                                </a>
                                <a href="ssas.php">
                                <li>
                                    SSAS
                                </li>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                <li>
                                    SAT C
                                </li>
                                </a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                            </div>
```

CSS:

```
* Service Sub */
.servicesub { padding:10px; }
.servicesub ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; color: #fff;}
.servicesub li{ font-size: 14px; height: 70px; padding: 17px 0px 10px 20px; margin-top: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; }
.servicesub li a {text-decoration: none;}
.servicesub li a:hover {color:#fff;}
.servicesub li { background-color: #017CEB; }
.servicesub li:hover { background-color: #015BAC; }
.servicesub li.active { background-color: #015BAC; }
.servicesub span:after { color:#fff; font-family: FontAwesome; display: inline-block;  width: 1.2em; font-size: 40px; position: absolute; text-align: center; margin-top: -9px; }
#servicesub.stick { position: fixed; top: 80px; max-width: 293px; }

.subitem { color:#fff; height:58px; width: 215px; position: absolute; right: 10px; text-align: center; }
.servicesubitem { cursor: pointer; }
.servicesubli { cursor: pointer; display: none; }
.servicesubli.default { display: block; }
.servicesubli ul { width: 100%; font-size: 14px;}
.servicesubli li {  padding: 8px; margin-top: 1px; text-transform: uppercase; height: 35px; text-align: center;}
.servicesubli a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }

.servicesub .getintouch { background-color: #00539f; padding: 10px; height: auto;}
.servicesub .getintouch:hover { background-color: #00539f; }
.servicesub .getintouch h3 { color: #fff; text-align: center; }
.servicesub .getintouch p { color:#fff; text-align: center; }
```

As you can see the accordion works to click on and the active class (which is set manually for this demo) is there I just want it so that the correct accordion part is toggled when the page is loaded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recycle your logic, You can just add your `.active` class to whichever element you wish, then search for `.servicesubli.active` on ready. Observe the following...

```
<div class="servicesubli active">
```

---

```
$(function() {

    [...]

    $('.servicesubli.active').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/p7oa0dxh/) - demo

---

Per comments, if you wish to target off `servicesubitem.active`, just modify to the following...

```
$('.servicesubitem.active').next('.servicesubli').addClass('active').slideToggle('fast');
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3o31p1/) - demo - `.servicesubitem.active` selector

Comment: Unfortunately this would mean editing hundreds of pages in order to be able to set that div as active. I really need it to work off the .servicesubitem .active class @scniro

Comment: And thats what I am doing, yo need to apply that class. You can do it programatically, but the point is that you'll need to select that one on page load. I am not fully understanding your concern

Comment: You have put the active class onto .servicesubli and for me to be able to do that I would have to edit hundreds of pages so that the active class could be set to them. I really want to find a way so that the .servicesubli under the already active .servicesubitem.active is expanded...

Comment: Please see if my update is addressing what you wish to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Well you just need to trigger the click event once the page is loaded like below:

```
$('.servicesub').find('.active').trigger( "click" );
```

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/beroza/a1mbgyqx/